# uTorrent true sequential download

Tags: utorrent

I've turned on sequential download in uTorrent, but from what I can see it retrieves data in blocks and doesn't wait to get 100% of the pieces before starting the next data block. So the first data block might still be 90% downloaded while getting close to downloading the entire torrent.

What I was wondering is if there is a way to modify some of the "Options > Preferences > Advanced" variables (or any other options from uTorrent) in order to force 100% block completion before starting the next data block so it will be a true sequential download. (I know this might decrease download speed, but that is not important to me)

I've found that modifying some of these variables make a difference, but I still have not figured out what the possible values should be or what other variables influence this behavior:

```
streaming.failover_rate_factor (default is 200)

streaming.failover_set_percentage (default is 70)

streaming.min_buffer_piece (default is 5)

streaming.safety_factor (default is 110)
```

Comment: sequential download only works from seeders not lechers.  Which means you won't always download the file pieces in sequential order from lechers even if you have this enabled.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to set uTorrent so I only download from seeders as a solution? As I said, download speed is not important to me.

Comment: What you are trying to do goes against the point of torrents. If you want to download a file sequentially only from servers, then use FTP, or HTTP, or a streaming protocol, etc.  Maybe your request will make more sense if you explain to us why you want to torrent the file parts in order? What benefit do you think it's going to get you (especially if transfer speed doesn't' matter)?

Comment: I'm working on a website that will interact with Torque (headless clone of uTorrent) through btapp.js ( http://btappjs.com/ ). I've experimented with trying to stream a video file to VLC, but VLC breaks eighter video or sound when the video file is not sequentially intact, I can't really fix VLC in this regard, so my only possibility is to try to make uTorrent download in exact order.

Comment: @Jaruba You can use qbittorrent